# Removing one numeric id and renaming the rest to a lower number (removed 101, want to change 102 to 101 and the rest for 344 ids))

Tags: excel

[enter image description here][1]Excel file with 3 columns (gonna be used for network analysis); first and second columns are my sample's ids (e.g 344 people, each person has a number assigned to them). I had to remove one person from my sample and now I need to rename the rest of the ideas. (removed 101, now need to rename 102->101, 103->102,...344->343)

I'm awfully new to excel, tried googling and looking up for same questions on here but as I'm not familiar with the jargon, I had no success.

edit: Sadly, I can't upload an image but I don't have any columns assigned to ids. Imagine I have two long columns with a bunch of numbers. (1-344).

Answer (score 0):

Make your `ID` column read as follows:

assuming you want to start IDs with `100` it's in column `A`, with header in `A1`, put the following in `A2`

```
=IFERROR(A1+1, 100)
```

Then expand it until the end of your table in excel.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Grzegorz Skibinski, I don't have a column assigned to ids. I edited my question. I'll truly appreciate it if you took a second look at it.

Comment: Hm, how is one id column connected with the second one ?

Comment: My first column is person 1, my second column is person 2. And I have almost 5000 rows. The third and last column is the label of their tie. (As I said it's gonna be used for network analysis, so, first column is node 1, second node2). These numbers have been assigned to them in a separate file.

Comment: Ou, if it's relation - then I dare say it's not for excel, but for VBA (alt+f11) and function you should look for: ```Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub``` (although how to exactly use it depends on your particular data and how do you code "delete")

Comment: Ah, seemingly way more complex than I thought. Thank you.